# How do I create a barplot that has the same denominator for each variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Will I have to create another column for each observation that is the proportion?

Here is the data:

```
count <- c(500, 200, 100, 75)
count_id <- c("6","15","20","21")
```

I was thinking creating a new column:

```
df <- data.frame(count_id,count)
df <- df %>% mutate(prop = count / 2000)
```

When plotting using ggplot2 - the x variable would be the count_id, what would the y variable be? I guess what I'm asking is I want the length of each variable to be 2000 and each variable should display the count?

Comment: Not clear.  Do you need `df %>% ggplot(aes(x = count_id, y = count)) + geom_col()`

Comment: Sorry. What I want is the length of each count_id should be 2000, and it's filled with the count .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very sure about what you want to visualize, but maybe plot another bar up to 2000 behind the actual counts?

```
ggplot(df) + geom_col(aes(x=count_id,y=count),fill="#efa8e4") + 
geom_col(aes(x=count_id,y=2000),alpha=.5,fill="#fff0f5") + 
theme_minimal() + 
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Yes - this is what I was looking for. Thanks